# How to control the positioning of a turtle on a patch?

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics

In order for two way traffic to flow along a road that is the thickness of a single patch it is necessary for the position of each turtle to be to either the left or the right of the patch on which they are travelling. How can I control where a turtle resides on a patch while travelling along it so that there is enough space for two opposing flows of traffic on the same road?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set xcor ...` and `set ycor ...`, or `setxy ... ...`, or any other turtle motion command such as `fd` or `bk`, to position the turtle however you like. If the turtle's coordinates are both integers, it's on a patch center. If either or both aren't integers, then the turtle is in some other location in the patch.